# VS Lighswitch and encryption

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have developed a Lightswitch application and now after some discussions with my Boss, he would like a couple of the Database Fields encrypted.  Now I haven't done any work with encrypting a Database Field but was wondering if Light switch natively supports encrypted fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, LightSwitch does not support that at all and that sort of encryption/decryption needs to be transparent to LightSwitch. You would have to use native database encryption which I believe might be supported by SQL Server.